# Weird face overlapping when exporting FBX

Tags: export, .fbx

I get weird overlapping when I export to FBX from Blender. It looks totally fine in Blender and there are no overlapping meshes, face orientation is correct, normals are correct yet when I export from Blender and check it in Windows 3D Viewer, it shows strange overlapping. How can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an edge split modifier and try exporting again, hope it helps